# Obligar a usuario cambiar contraseña LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Yo doy de alta a usuarios con su correo y le doy una contraseña para que se inicie sesión, pero la tiene que cambiar la primera ves que entre. Para detectar esto, he puesto a cada usuario un `boolean` con nombre `cambiarPass`, que por defecto es `false`. Entonces mi intención es que cuando acceda e inicie sesión y compruebe que este booleano es `false`, lo redirija al formulario para cambiar de contraseña, y si es el booleano es `true` pues que lo redirija al `/main`. Yo tengo lo siguiente.

Mi middleare changePass:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->cambiarPass==0) {
            return "debes cambiar de contraseña"; //ruta de formulario para cambiar contraseña
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Las rutas, web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']],function(){

        Route::post('/logout','Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

        //--------ADMINISTRADOR------//
        Route::group(['middleware'=>['Administrador']],function(){
            Route::get('/main', function () {
                return view('contenido/contenido');
            })->name('main');

            //---------PERSONAS---------//
            Route::get('/persona', 'PersonaController@index');
            Route::get('/persona/desactivados', 'PersonaController@desactivados');
            Route::get('/persona/nombre', 'PersonaController@nombre');
            Route::get('/persona/nombreDesact', 'PersonaController@nombreDesact');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido1', 'PersonaController@apellido1');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido1Desact', 'PersonaController@apellido1Desact');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido2', 'PersonaController@apellido2');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido2Desact', 'PersonaController@apellido2Desact');
            Route::get('/persona/telefono', 'PersonaController@telefono');
            Route::get('/persona/telefonoDesact', 'PersonaController@telefonoDesact');
            Route::get('/persona/correo', 'PersonaController@correo');
            Route::get('/persona/correoDesact', 'PersonaController@correoDesact');
            Route::get('/persona/rol', 'PersonaController@rol');
            Route::get('/persona/rolDesact', 'PersonaController@rolDesact');
            Route::post('/persona/registrar','PersonaController@store');
            Route::put('/persona/actualizar','PersonaController@update');

            //---------PERMISOS---------//
            Route::get('/permiso','PermisoController@index');
            Route::post('/permiso/registrar','PermisoController@store');
            Route::put('/permiso/actualizar','PermisoController@update');
            Route::put('/permiso/eliminar','PermisoController@eliminar');

            //------ROLES-------//
            Route::get('/rol','RolController@index');

            //---------AUSENCIAS---------//
            Route::get('/ausencia','AusenciaController@index');
            Route::post('/ausencia/registrar','AusenciaController@store');
            Route::put('/ausencia/actualizar','AusenciaController@update');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarPermiso','AusenciaController@filtrarPermiso');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarInicio','AusenciaController@filtrarInicio');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarFinal','AusenciaController@filtrarFinal');


            //---------AUSENCIAS-ADMIN---------//
            Route::get('/ausencia/admin','AusenciaAdminController@indexAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarEmpleadoAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarEmpleadoAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarPermisoAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarPermisoAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarInicioAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarInicioAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarFinalAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarFinalAdmin');


            //---------REGISTROS---------//
            Route::get('/registro','RegistroController@index');
            Route::post('/registro/registrar','RegistroController@store');
            Route::put('/registro/actualizar','RegistroController@update');
            Route::put('/registro/eliminar', 'RegistroController@eliminar');


            //---------REGISTROS-ADMIN---------//
            //Muestra registros de todos los empleados, asignar a los usuarios admin
            Route::get('/registro/admin','RegistroAdminController@indexAdmin');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarEmpleadoAdmin','RegistroAdminController@filtrarEmpleadoAdmin');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarInicioAdmin','RegistroAdminController@filtrarInicioAdmin');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarFinalAdmin','RegistroAdminController@filtrarFinalAdmin');


            //----REGSITRSO-ADMIN-USERS-DESACTVIADOS----//
            //Muestra los regisotrs de los empleados desactivados, se usa en el vue Registroantiguosempleados
            Route::get('/registro/adminDesact','RegistroAdminController@indexAdminDesactivados');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarEmpleadoAdminDesact','RegistroAdminController@filtrarEmpleadoAdminDesact');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarInicioAdminDesact','RegistroAdminController@filtrarInicioAdminDesact');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarFinalAdminDesact','RegistroAdminController@filtrarFinalAdminDesact');


        });        

        //-----EMPLEADO-----//
        Route::group(['middleware'=>['Empleado']],function(){

            Route::group(['middleware' => ['ChangePassword']], function () {
                return "Debes cambiar la contraseña";
            });

            Route::get('/main', function () {
                return view('contenido/contenido');
            })->name('main');

            //PODER VER MIS REGISTROS
            Route::get('/registro','RegistroController@index');
            Route::post('/registro/registrar','RegistroController@store');
            Route::put('/registro/actualizar','RegistroController@update');
            Route::put('/registro/eliminar', 'RegistroController@eliminar');

            //MIS AUSENCIAS
            Route::get('/ausencia','AusenciaController@index');
            Route::post('/ausencia/registrar','AusenciaController@store');
            Route::put('/ausencia/actualizar','AusenciaController@update');
        });


});
```

LoginController

```
public function login(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request,[
          'email'=>'required|string',
          'password'=>'required|string'
      ]);

       if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password])){

           return redirect()->route('main');
        }

       return back()
       ->withErrors(['email' => trans('auth.failed')])
       ->withInput(request(['email']));

  }
```

Posible opcion de loginController, pero realmente no entiendo bien que hace el if en la funcion del middleware 'ChangePassword'.

```
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password,'cambiarPass'=>1])){

               return redirect()->route('main');

   }elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password,'cambiarPass'=>0])){
              return view("cambiarContraseña");
   }
```

Comment: Hay por lo menos un problema en tu logica. Pero cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Creo que te seria mas cómodo no modificar el auth y meter un nuevo midleware que se dedique solo a ver si el user tiene esa condición

Comment: Si supongo que te refieres a que las rutas de 'restablecer contraseña' no pueden estar en 'guest' y 'auth', lo comprobé. Si asi lo haré Manuel gracias por tu ayudaa

Answer (score 2):

Yo creé un middleware para hacer eso, no lo puedo compartir porque es de código cerrado, pero te voy a resumir la lógica de mi middleware;

1- Añadí una columna "changed_password" de tipo datetime y predeterminado nulo.
2- En el middleware comprueba si el campo changed_password es nulo, si es nulo redirige a la vista de cambio de contraseña, si no, continua.
FIN

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckChangePassword
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!isset($request->user()->changedpassword)) {
            return redirect('changepassword');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Como ves es un middleware bien sencillito, como sugerencia, yo puse el middleware como un grupo de enrutación para que no pudieran saltarse el cambio de contraseña de ninguna manera.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['changepassword']], function () {
    // Aquí las rutas a las que no quieras que entren
});
```

Espero que te funcione!!

***EDIT:***

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']],function(){

        Route::post('/logout','Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

        //--------ADMINISTRADOR------//
        Route::group(['middleware'=>['Administrador']],function(){
            Route::get('/main', function () {
                return view('contenido/contenido');
            })->name('main');

            //---------PERSONAS---------//
            Route::get('/persona', 'PersonaController@index');
            Route::get('/persona/desactivados', 'PersonaController@desactivados');
            Route::get('/persona/nombre', 'PersonaController@nombre');
            Route::get('/persona/nombreDesact', 'PersonaController@nombreDesact');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido1', 'PersonaController@apellido1');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido1Desact', 'PersonaController@apellido1Desact');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido2', 'PersonaController@apellido2');
            Route::get('/persona/apellido2Desact', 'PersonaController@apellido2Desact');
            Route::get('/persona/telefono', 'PersonaController@telefono');
            Route::get('/persona/telefonoDesact', 'PersonaController@telefonoDesact');
            Route::get('/persona/correo', 'PersonaController@correo');
            Route::get('/persona/correoDesact', 'PersonaController@correoDesact');
            Route::get('/persona/rol', 'PersonaController@rol');
            Route::get('/persona/rolDesact', 'PersonaController@rolDesact');
            Route::post('/persona/registrar','PersonaController@store');
            Route::put('/persona/actualizar','PersonaController@update');

            //---------PERMISOS---------//
            Route::get('/permiso','PermisoController@index');
            Route::post('/permiso/registrar','PermisoController@store');
            Route::put('/permiso/actualizar','PermisoController@update');
            Route::put('/permiso/eliminar','PermisoController@eliminar');

            //------ROLES-------//
            Route::get('/rol','RolController@index');

            //---------AUSENCIAS---------//
            Route::get('/ausencia','AusenciaController@index');
            Route::post('/ausencia/registrar','AusenciaController@store');
            Route::put('/ausencia/actualizar','AusenciaController@update');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarPermiso','AusenciaController@filtrarPermiso');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarInicio','AusenciaController@filtrarInicio');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarFinal','AusenciaController@filtrarFinal');


            //---------AUSENCIAS-ADMIN---------//
            Route::get('/ausencia/admin','AusenciaAdminController@indexAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarEmpleadoAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarEmpleadoAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarPermisoAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarPermisoAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarInicioAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarInicioAdmin');
            Route::get('/ausencia/filtrarFinalAdmin','AusenciaAdminController@filtrarFinalAdmin');


            //---------REGISTROS---------//
            Route::get('/registro','RegistroController@index');
            Route::post('/registro/registrar','RegistroController@store');
            Route::put('/registro/actualizar','RegistroController@update');
            Route::put('/registro/eliminar', 'RegistroController@eliminar');


            //---------REGISTROS-ADMIN---------//
            //Muestra registros de todos los empleados, asignar a los usuarios admin
            Route::get('/registro/admin','RegistroAdminController@indexAdmin');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarEmpleadoAdmin','RegistroAdminController@filtrarEmpleadoAdmin');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarInicioAdmin','RegistroAdminController@filtrarInicioAdmin');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarFinalAdmin','RegistroAdminController@filtrarFinalAdmin');


            //----REGSITRSO-ADMIN-USERS-DESACTVIADOS----//
            //Muestra los regisotrs de los empleados desactivados, se usa en el vue Registroantiguosempleados
            Route::get('/registro/adminDesact','RegistroAdminController@indexAdminDesactivados');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarEmpleadoAdminDesact','RegistroAdminController@filtrarEmpleadoAdminDesact');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarInicioAdminDesact','RegistroAdminController@filtrarInicioAdminDesact');
            Route::get('/registro/filtrarFinalAdminDesact','RegistroAdminController@filtrarFinalAdminDesact');


        });        

                    //-----EMPLEADO-----//
        Route::group(['middleware'=>['Empleado']],function(){
            Route::group(['middleware' => ['ChangePassword']], function () {
                Route::get('/main', function () {
                    return view('contenido/contenido');
                })->name('main');

                //PODER VER MIS REGISTROS
                Route::get('/registro','RegistroController@index');
                Route::post('/registro/registrar','RegistroController@store');
                Route::put('/registro/actualizar','RegistroController@update');
                Route::put('/registro/eliminar', 'RegistroController@eliminar');

                //MIS AUSENCIAS
                Route::get('/ausencia','AusenciaController@index');
                Route::post('/ausencia/registrar','AusenciaController@store');
                Route::put('/ausencia/actualizar','AusenciaController@update');
            });
        });


});
```

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo, graciaas :D

Comment: El problema que tengo es que los usuarios ya tiene un middleware, lo q hago es poner el Route::group(['middleware' => ['changepassword']], function () {
}); DENTRO DEL route groupp middleware=>['empleado'], esto seria correcto?, de momento no funciona pero puede ser por otra razón.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, échale un vistazo porfaa, gracias

Comment: es al revés @smiranda, dentro del grupo de enrutación deben ir las rutas!! edito mi respuesta en como debería quedar ;)

Comment: Graciaas bueno si funciona mas o menos, es decir no te permite ejecutar ninguna acción pero se mete al main cosa que es normal ya que en mi loginController redirigo al main. Deberia o me recomiendas a que para hacer el auth::attempt en mi loginController ponga una tercera condicion de que el boolean debe de estar en true para que pueda entrar? Publico mi loginControoler en la pregunta.

Comment: Si tienes el middleware changePassword NO puedes acceder al main no? eso es lo que le estoy diciendo en el codigo que has publicado?(lo q has editado)

Comment: Valee he conseguido que ya no pueda acceder al main, si te fijas hemos puesto dentro del middleware 'changePassword' la ruta del main para que NO pueda accedar pero igualmente accedia, (solo pasaba con el main, las otras rutas si las bloqueaba) , era porque dentro del middlware 'Administrador' tmb tenia puesto la ruta get del main, no le veo mucho sentido la verdad, por que si este usuario tiene rol empleado puede acceder a rutas que estan en el middlware de administrador

Comment: Perdona, he estado ocupado estos días. Exactamente, dentro del middleware changepassword deben estar TODAS las rutas que no quieras que sean accesibles antes de haber cambiado la contraseña. Lo lógico es ponerlo justo despues del middleware de auth de laravel y luego, poner más middlewares dentro (excluyendo si fuera necesario las rutas que quieras que accedan aunque no hayan cambiado la contraseña, ToS, RGPD, etc)

Comment: No te preocupes, gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda :D